# URL-Rewriting /Anything/Variable detail.php?pid=variable

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, search-engine

o/

I am trying to rewrite my URL's.

If i'd go to: `http://mydomain.com/vakanties/Verenigde%20Staten/Orlando/E6220`

it should get parsed to:  `http://mydomain.com/detail.php?pid=E6220`

However, X should be able to be any random word, including spaces and special characters

`http://mydomain.com/vakanties/ X / X / Y`

Everything I've tried has resulted me with a 404 so far. The module is activated and the engine is on. These are the rules that I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^vakanties/[\w +]/[\w +]/([\w]*) detail.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^vakanties/[A-Za-z0-9-]+/[A-Za-z0-9-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) detail.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^vakanties/[a-zA-Z0-9%+]/[a-zA-Z0-9%+]/([a-zA-Z0-9%+]*)$ detail.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^vakanties/[\w\ +]/[\w\ +]/([\w]*) detail.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^vakanties/[\w\ +]/[\w\ +]/([\w]*)$ detail.php?pid=$1
```

Any help, links, suggestions or tips would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `[\w +]` use negation regex like `[^/]+` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^vakanties/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ detail.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Much appriciated. However it appears that I'd also need similar rules for my CSS and Images?